# Diamonds are too big in area 51 user references

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The diamonds are cut in the top, because they are either too big or need to be placed differently in the user reference image:

[Screen shot of Jeff http://grab.by/grabs/15a1e5988c7492769a279531e3f93e8a.png](http://grab.by/grabs/15a1e5988c7492769a279531e3f93e8a.png)

**Update**

The above screenshot is from safari 5.0.4 on OS 10.6

I also tested with some version of Chrome on OS 10.6 and webkit trunk which gave identical result. Not surprisingly, since they use the same engine.

I can verify that I'm using the default font-size. I tried messing with the `.user-details` `div`  decreasing the font size. I needed to decrease it quite a bit, to be able to get the diamonds to fit:

[decreased font size http://grab.by/grabs/4e5ffa59c46bc5aba9072593146466fe.png](http://grab.by/grabs/4e5ffa59c46bc5aba9072593146466fe.png)

I hope this helps to identify a solution to make the text/diamond proportions more equal. For safari, reducing the `140%` font-size to `100%` makes the diamonds close to firefox size.

Comment: heheh, not that big on my browsers though :D may be font issue?

Comment: Are you saying that Jeff's precious stones are just too darn big?

Comment: which OS, Browser btw?

Comment: In XP and Chrome, I don't see any issues.

Comment: @YOU seems like a safari issue, it looks fine on other browsers. Doubt it's my font size though. If it were, the name and rep should be a lot bigger as well.

Comment: Your diamond is just shown with a table cut rather than the usual point cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think font issue in browser/OS. here is mine for reference

Ubuntu versions

Chrome 12 dev

[image]

Firefox 4

[image]

Opera 11 (quite big, but still fit in box)

[image]

**Edit**:

I am not sure which font should be default font on OSX, but changing it to **Arial** solve it for me on Safari, and Chrome at OSX

```
javascript:$(".mod-flair").css("font-family","Arial")
```

[image]

To

[image]

Comment: I updated with more info, should be enough to reproduce the problem :)